# What is the closest Windows equivalent to the POSIX wait mechanism?

Tags: c, windows, monitoring, wait, status

Linux supports the POSIX wait mechanism defined in "sys/wait.h". The methods [wait, waitid, waitpid](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) might be used to exchange status information between parent and child processes that have been created using [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork).

Windows neither does provide (native) support for fork nor the POSIX wait mechanism. Instead there are other means available to spwan child processes i.e. [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

When porting linux applications written in C or C++ using fork/wait to Windows what would the most proper *native** way to monitor state changes (namely [WEXITED, WSTOPPED, WCONTINUED](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)) of child processes in the parent process?

**native* meaning using no additional libraries, frameworks, programs (like cygwin, minGW) that do not ship with windows or are provided directly by MS in form of runtime environments.

*Edit:* As requested in the comments I did provide some more information about what problem should be solved in form of pseudo code:

```
//creates a new child process that is a copy of the parent (compare 
//POSIX fork()) and returns some sort of handle to it.
function spawnChild() 

// returns TRUE if called from the master process FALSE otherwise
function master()

// return TRUE if called from a child process FALSE otherwise
function child()

// returns TRUE if child process has finished its work entirely, 
// FALSE otherwise.
function completelyFinished()

//sends signal/message "sig" to receive where receiver is a single 
//handle or a set of handles to processes that shall receive sig
function sendSignal(sig, receiver)

// terminates the calling process
function exit()

// returns a handle to the sender of signal "sig"
function senderOf(sig)

function masterprocess()
  master //contains handle to the master process
  children = {}   //this is an empty set of handles to child processes
  buf[SIZE]  //some memory area of SIZE bytes available to master process and all children
  FOR i = 0 TO n - 1
    //spawn new child process and at its handle to the list of running 
    //child processes.
    children <- children UNION spawnChild() 
  IF(master())
    <logic here>
    sendSignal(STARTWORKING, children) //send notification to children
    WHILE(signal = wait())  // wait for any child to respond (wait is blocking) 
      IF signal == IMDONE
        <logic here (involving reads/writes to buf)>
        sendSignal(STARTWORKING, senderOf(signal))
      ELSEIF signal == EXITED
        children <- children \ signal.sender //remove sender from list of children
  ELSEIF(child())
    WHILE(wait() != STARTWORKING);
       <logic here (involving reads/writes to buf)>
       IF completelyFinished()
         sendSignal(EXITED, master)
         exit()
       ELSE
         sendSignal(IMDONE, master)
```

Comment: Windows processes don't have the same "states" as POSIX processes. If you want to wait for the process to exit, you can either poll with GetExitCodeProcess, or simply use WaitForSingleObject (or one of its relatives) with the process handle.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe While being aware that windows probably doesn't support those exact signals I still assume ther must be sth. related. Imagine you share some memory between processes (i.e. using CreateFileMapping). So rather than brute force polling for changes on that memory from every single process there (hopefully) needs to be some way for any of the related processes to tell the others "Hey guys, I've done sth. please check if the changes are important to you" or alternatively "Hey I've put some request into memory please someone responsible process it and notify me when you're done".

Comment: So you are really interested in inter process communication and do not care about Posix signals at all?

Comment: Yeah, if you're looking for IPC to flag (e.g.) "I've written to the file mapping", then you want a shared (usually named) event. See CreateEvent.

Comment: @usr Yes I'm pretty much interested in *any* appropriate mechanism that most closely resembles the behaviour of said POSIX signals. When speaking of resemblence this means the port should have similar semantics and resemble the underlying concept as close as possible. Syntax is expected to be very different though.

Comment: "any appropriate mechanism that most closely resembles the behaviour of said POSIX signals". There really isn't anything close. Win32 doesn't work like that. What's the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I added some pseudo code to describe the typical underlying problem. To be clear I'm not worried about the signature, name or retrun value or involved types. The basic question is - How would a highly experienced Windows API programmer implement the task described by above pseudo code.

Comment: Sounds like you want [Named Pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590.aspx). The pipe server gets notified when clients attach/detach from the client end. It also gets notified, when a client writes to the client end. A pipe supports one server and one or more clients, duplex communication, and message-based (transactional) mode.

Comment: Just curious: How can a child process use `WEXITED`, `WSTOPPED`, and `WCONTINUED` to signal its parent that data has changed? You can't exit more than once. If you stop, you cannot continue yourself.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes actually those signal IDs are ORed together as a bitmask so the POSIX wait will only return on reception of signals that match the provided bitmask. In this case the funtion will return on receiving any of WEXITED, WSTOPPED *or* WCONTINUED. If you only provide WEXITED as argument WSTOPPED and WCONTINUED will be ignored and wait will still continue waiting, even if one of the latter signals has been received.

Comment: @norritt I mean, how does the child uses these signals to notify the parent that it changed the shared data? Does it intentionally stop itself, and then the parent processes the change, then the parent continues the child? That seems awfully strange.

Comment: @RaymondChen Actually it is not necessarily the parent that stops or continues the child, it could be the kernel or another process (i.e. shell command kill invoked by a user). Accordingly there is a [kill function](http://tinyurl.com/oxxu9br) the child can use to signal the parent or even use [raise](http://tinyurl.com/p75e657) to signal yourself. WHILE SIGSTOP and SIGCONT could be utilized there are also special signals SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2 for custom use. To signal the parent the child could invoke kill(parentPid, SIGCONT).

Comment: @norritt But your program is not doing `kill(parentPid, SIGCONT)` because that comes in as a signal, not as something you `waitid` for. I'm trying to understand how the original unix program is designed, so that children generate stop, continue, and exit events on themselves in order to communicate with the parent. That to me is the weird part. The Windows way is to use an IPC mechanism instead of trying to jam IPC into child process lifetime notifications.

Comment: @RaymondChen The example is provided in pseudo code. For simplicity lets just assume that the pseudo code sendSignal(STARTWORKING, senderOf(signal)) correlates to POSIX kill(senderPid, SIGCONT).

Comment: @norritt Okay, and I guess `sendSignal(IMDONE, master)` is the equivalent of `kill(childPid, SIGSTOP)`. As others noted, instead of using process state transitions as pseudo-IPC, use something actually designed for IPC, like an event.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: Yes that's the basic idea. One big problem still is I know I can create custom events using "CreateEvent" in Windows. But those won't actually notify me about any signals from the outside. I.e. someone kills the master process with the task manager. On POSIX systems I will be notified with SIGKILL, on windows the master process will never notice if my custom CreateEvent-Handler can't be invoked before the OS kills the process. Same goes for crashing, Ctrl-C ... so what is still missing is some "GetProcessKilledEventHandler" doing the job in windows.

Comment: *Why* do you care that the master process was killed with the task manager? *Why* do you care that a child process was killed? What are you going to do with that information?

Comment: You're trying to put a square peg (POSIX) into a round hole (Win32). You can get it in there if you jam it hard enough, but it's going to be a lot of work, and you're not going to get the best results.

Comment: You can detect that a process has exited by simply waiting on the process handle.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I care so that I for instance can remove handles from the list of childProcess handles, so that the master process doesn't wait eternally for children that are long gone.

Comment: Yeah, so `WaitForMultipleObjects(hProcesses, ...)` will wake up when one of the child processes goes away. The return value will tell you which one. Remove it from the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I answer the actual question, I'm going to recommend a better solution: you should consider simplifying the relationship between the parent and children.

Based on the pseudocode, the signals between parent and children are serving as a crude form of [cross-process mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx), i.e., all they do is to prevent the code here:

```
  IF signal == IMDONE
    <logic here (involving reads/writes to buf)>
    sendSignal(STARTWORKING, senderOf(signal))
```

from running multiple instances simultaneously.  Instead, `<logic here>` should be moved into the corresponding child process, protected by a mutex so that only one child can run it at a time.

At that point, all the parent needs to do is to launch the children and wait for them all to exit.  That is easily done in Windows by waiting on the process handle.

(I would imagine that modern POSIX also supports some sort of cross-process mutex somewhat more sophisticated than signals.)

---

It would also be worth reconsidering whether you really really need multiple processes.  Multiple threads would be more efficient, and if the code is properly written, it should not be difficult to adapt it.

---

**Be that as it may,** if for some reason you absolutely *must* retain as much of the original program structure as possible, [pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365780(v=vs.85).aspx) are probably going to be your best bet.

- Sending a signal becomes writing a single byte.
- In a child, waiting for a signal from the parent becomes reading a single byte.
- Waiting in the parent for a message from any of the children is a little trickier. It is still a single-byte read (for each child) but you'll need to use [overlapped I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365603(v=vs.85).aspx) and, if you need to support more than 64 children, [IOCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx).

(Alternatively, you could use multiple threads, but that might involve too much of a structural change.)

- If the pipes are implemented correctly, when a child exits or dies the corresponding read operation in the parent will terminate with the `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` error.  So there is no need for a separate mechanism to monitor the health of the children.

In this context, I think [anonymous pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152(v=vs.85).aspx) would be the most appropriate choice.  These are simplex, so you'll need two pipes for each child.  You can pass the child's end of the pipe handles as the standard input and output for the child process.

For anonymous pipes, you will need to make sure that you close the parent's copy of the handles once each child has been started, and also that each child only inherits the handles corresponding to its own pipe.  If there are any additional handles left open to the child's end of its pipe, the parent will not receive any notification when the child exits.

---

None of this is particularly complicated, but be aware that named pipe I/O has a bit of a learning curve.  Asynchronous I/O even more so, particularly if you are coming from a UNIX background.  Note in particular that to use asynchronous I/O, you issue an operation and then wait for it to complete, as opposed to the UNIX model where you wait for the I/O to be ready and then issue the operation.

Comment: Very nice, detailed answer, it is the most helpful by far since you stay on topic regarding the requirement that processes shall communicate to each others not threads. Also your elaborations regarding the differences between the Windows and POSIX way are helpful. For the interested reader I want to point out that [named pipes](http://bit.ly/1O36PN8) are also available on POSIX systems. I believe there is an alternative way to do it by combining `CreateFileMapping`, `CreateProcess`, `CreateEvent`, `WaitForMultipleObjects`/`WaitForSingleObject` and `GetExitCodeProcess`.

Comment: Concerning your assumtion that "POSIX also supports some sort of cross-process mutex somewhat more sophisticated than signals". Yes it does, just like in Windows this can be done via [Semaphores](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to signal boolean conditions to other processes you probably should use shared events for that. You can share them by name or by handle duplication. You can have as many of these signals as you like. For example, you could have one for each of `WEXITED, WSTOPPED, WCONTINUED`.

Seeing your edit: Events are great for that. Create named events in the parent and pass their names on the command like to the children. That way parent and child can signal each other.

You also need to share a memory section, for example though a memory mapped file. That would correspond to `buf` in your code.

Comment: You get as many events, as the object manager allows you to. You cannot create event objects when the system runs out of resources, or the caller reached its quota limit. This is not necessarily *"as many [...] as you like"*.

Comment: @IInspectable that is true... Do you see the risk that he wants to create millions of events? I thought more like 3.

Comment: It's not entirely necessary to misrepresent the situation either. Stating that you can create as many event objects as you like neither adds anything useful to the answer, nor is it correct. Like all resources, kernel object resources are limited.

Comment: You can't create an unlimited number of *anything*. I don't think this text can reasonably be interpreted to mean that.

Comment: @usr I guess shared events with CreateEvent might work if the program terminates as expected. A program might also crash, be killed by Ctrl+C or the task manager. In this case the POSIX system still notifies the master thread. This will probably be not the case for custom events see[WIFEXITED, WEXITSTATUS, WIFSIGNALED, WCOREDUMP...](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait). What's the best practice in windows to handle such cases? Are there appropriate predifined events available, or is there a hookable callback available that can be used to call custom exit events on termination?

Comment: In Windows, many handles are waitable. Process handles are and get signaled when the process exits. You can wait for processes to die. You can wait for multiple at once using WaitForMultipleObjects. I believe in newer Windows versions you can make Windows post a callback to a thread pool when a handle becomes signaled.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there appears to be a work queue arrangement, where you have a producer process and a bunch of worker processes. It's unclear whether you're using the shared memory merely as a work queue, or whether your workers are operating *on* the shared memory (maybe it's a massive matrix or vector problem).

In Win32, you probably wouldn't implement this as separate processes.

You'd use a collection of producer/consumer threads, which are already sharing memory (same address space), and you'd implement a work queue using semaphores or condition variables.

In fact, you'd probably use a higher-level abstraction, such as [QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684957.aspx). This uses the default Windows thread pool, but you can create your own thread pool, using [CreateThreadpool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682456.aspx).

Comment: That actually is a good point. I blindly assumed there was a need for multiple processes. OP should clarify.

Comment: Threads are not an option in this case. While there is also a [POSIX threads standard](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html), I'm asking purposefully about an approach explicitly involving seperate processes *not* threads. As stated in my original question Windows also supports fork-like spawning of seprate processes using [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @norritt: There's nothing *"fork-like"* about [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx). It can optionally inherit handles to its 'child' process (and certain state), but other than that, there is no relation between the child and the parent. While Windows records the PID of the parent process, it's not being used for anything. Once launched, child and parent run completely independent of each other.

Comment: @IInspectable: Does CreateProcess create a new process (not a thread) from inside a process invoking it? If it does it is "fork-like" because that is what fork does. If you know any Windows API functions that behave even more fork-like than CreateProcess I'm happy to hear about them.

Comment: @norritt: Every process is created from inside a process. There really is no other way to do it, so that's not really a unique feature of `fork`, and surely doesn't make `CreateProcess` *"fork-like"*. The main difference between `CreateProcess` and `fork` is, that the former creates a fresh process object, whereas the latter creates a copy of an existing process (including all of its owned resources). There is nothing that resembles `fork` in the Windows API.

Comment: @IInspectable I assume that there is nothing available in Windows which **exactly** resembles fork. This is why in my original question asks for the **closest** equivalent. Which to my knowledge is CreateProcess. If there were exactly matching implementations of the POSIX standard available in Windows I wouldn't have to ask this question but could simply compile the original linux code for Windows.

Comment: @norritt: Your question isn't specific (or even related) to `fork`ing. It's asking for ways to implement IPC and synchronization across process boundaries. Maybe you need to rework your question to ask, what you are really trying to solve. Asking for something *"fork-like"* in Windows is futile: There isn't anything *"fork-like"* in Windows.

Comment: My question is very specific. As you said I'm asking for ways to "implement IPC and synchronization across process boundaries". In order to do so I need to spawn processes, correct? So the creation of processses is necessarily related to that question, because I can not communicate with other processes or sychronize with them if there aren't other processes there to communicate or synchronize with.

Comment: Why are you using separate processes? If it's for process isolation, you've already shot yourself in the foot by using shared memory. If it's for efficient use of multiple CPUs, just use threads. Multiple processes is the (pre-pthreads) POSIX paradigm. Multiple threads is more common in Win32 programming.